# TYPO3 fetch news records title in multi language application

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news, typo3-8.x

I want to add the current news article title to my breadcrumb navigation. Following is my output:

[image: Breadcrumb output]

URL:

**Default (German)**

index.phpid=19&

L=0&

tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=1&

tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&

tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&

cHash=b182adf919054989c8d640e1da19f0a2

**English**

index.php?id=19&

tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=1&

tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&

tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&

L=1&

cHash=b182adf919054989c8d640e1da19f0a2

**French**

index.phpid=19&

L=2&

tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=1&

tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&

tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&

cHash=b182adf919054989c8d640e1da19f0a2

As you can see the last part in my breadcrumb navigation won't get translated. Following my TypoScript for the news title output.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
lib.nav_breadcrumb.20 = RECORDS
lib.nav_breadcrumb.20 {

    tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
    dontCheckPid = 1

    source {
        data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        intval = 1
    }

    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.field = title
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.htmlSpecialChars = 1

    wrap = <li class="breadcrumb-item active">|</li>

}
[global]
```

This now fetches the title from the news records. But only from the main language. How can I fetch the other languages?

My System:

- TYPO3 Version **8.7.11**
- Webserver **Apache**
- PHP Version  **7.0.27-0+deb9u1**
- Database (Default) **MySQL 5.5.5**
- Application Context **Production**
- Composer mode **Enabled**
- Operating System **Linux 4.9.0-5-amd64**
- News Extension **6.3.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to activate sys_language_overlay. And now everything works

```
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `RECORDS` you should use `CONTENT` where you have more [options](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/ContentObjects/Content/) to select the records you want.
With `CONTENT` you can change the query to select the record which has that `sys_language_uid` you want to show, of course you need to select `l10n_parent` instead of `uid` for languages other than default:
use a TS condition or `stdwrap.if` to build two kinds of selections.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just had to activate sys_language_overlay and it worked then.