# Typoscript records not translated content

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a piece of typoscript code, it works nice for the main language but does not translate?

```
20 = RECORDS
20 {
    source.data = field:pid
    tables = pages
    conf.pages = TEXT
    conf.pages.field = title
    wrap = <li class="text-li"><h2>|</h2>
}
```

How to get the translated "title" field from database?

p.s. This code is working with fallbackType: fallback, but not with the current fallbackType: free

We want to keep free enabled because the site is already filled by the editors in this manner

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429316/typo3-fetch-news-records-title-in-multi-language-application?rq=1

Comment: In short: Use CONTENT object instead of RECORDS object.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Thomas Löffler:

```
20 = CONTENT
        20 {
            table = pages
            select {
                where = (l10n_parent={field:pid} AND sys_language_uid={field:sys_language_uid}) OR (uid={field:pid})
                where.insertData = 1
            }
            slide = -1
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                10 = TEXT
                10.stdWrap.field = title
                10.stdWrap.wrap = <li class="text-li"><h2>|</h2>
            }
        }
```